# The background image of my button won't display in simulator (xcode)

Tags: xcode, image, button

(I'm using xcode 4) I'm trying to add a button and give it an image or background image, so I put in the image through the attributes inspector. However when I test the app in simulator the button is just blank with no image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should verify that the image is bundled with your app. Select the target, go to the **Build Phases** tab, and check that the image is located in the **Copy Bundle Resources** list. If it is not there, add it.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou thankyou thankyou! It worked! do I have to do this with every image I want to use as a button?

Comment: When you add a file to the project, there is a check box that you can use to tell Xcode to add the file automatically to the target, it is named **Add to targets**.

Comment: If you use image which is copied into the bundle via folder reference (not group reference), make sure you add folder name before image name in interface builder.